# How to get the name of the user that was clicked and send it to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I'm having a problem that I can't solve. I have a component that is currently rendering the users that are in my database, which calls CarouselUsers.jsx, so far so good, it is showing correctly.
But my goal is that after I click on one of these users that were listed, his name appears in a sidebar, which is in another component, but I am not able to do that, can you help me?

CarouselUsers.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Styled from './style.jsx';
import {
    collection,
    getDocs,
  } from "firebase/firestore";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { db } from '../../Data/Firebase.jsx';
import "swiper/css";
import euTeste from '../../assets/teste.jfif'
import SideBarProfile from '../../components/SideBarProfile/SideBarProfile.jsx';


export default function CarouselUsers() {

  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(false)  
  const openProfile = () => {
    setProfile(profile => !profile)      
  }

    
// USERS IN THE DB
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "usuarios")

  useEffect(() => {    
    const getUsers = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(usersCollectionRef);
      setUsers(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))); 
    };

    getUsers();
    
  }, []);
// USERS IN THE DB
 
  return (
    <>
    <Styled.CarouselUsers>
    {/* MEMBROS CARROSEL */}
    <div className="boxMembros">
        <div className="titulo">
            <h6>Membros</h6>
        </div>
        <Swiper
        spaceBetween={10}
        slidesPerView={3}
        > 
        {users.map((user) => {                    
        return (
            <>
            <SwiperSlide>
                <div className="box"style={{ background: `linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.6) 100%),url(${euTeste})` }} onClick={openProfile} key={user.nome}>
                    <div className="infoBottom">
                        <div className="info">   
                        {/* GET THE USERNAME */}
                        <h6>{user.nome}</h6>
                        {/* GET THE USERNAME */}
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </SwiperSlide>                  
        </>
        );
        })}
        </Swiper>
    </div>
    {/* MEMBROS CARROSEL */}       
    </Styled.CarouselUsers>    
    <SideBarProfile profile={profile} openProfile={openProfile} />
    </>
  )
}
```

SideBarProfile.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { XCircle,WhatsappLogo } from "phosphor-react";
import * as Styled from './style.jsx';
export default function SideBarProfile({openProfile,profile}) {  
  return (
        
    <Styled.SideBarProfile>
        <div className={profile ? 'col-md-3 boxLeftWrapper open' : 'col-md-3 boxLeftWrapper close'} profile={profile}>
            <div className="boxAll">
              <div className="header d-flex justify-between align-items-center">
                <div className="titulo">
                  <h1>Perfil</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="close">
                  <button onClick={openProfile}>
                    <XCircle/>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="boxBodyUser text-left">
                <div className="boxThis">
                    <div className="foto">
                    <img  alt="Usuário" className='img-fluid ativo' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="nome text-center">
                      <h5>{/* SHOW USERNAME  */}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div className="status ativo">
                    <span>Ativo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="ministerios">
                    <ul className="pl-0 list-none mb-0">
                        <li>Teatro</li>
                        <li>Mídias Sociais</li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="boxContato  mt-5">
                    <div className="whatsapp d-flex items-center justify-center gap-2">
                        <WhatsappLogo/>
                        <span>Mensagem</span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        </Styled.SideBarProfile>    
  )
}
```

Comment: Make a context and wrap both of those components under the same provider,make the carousel component to mutate the context onClick and make the sidebar component to listen to that context value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `onClick event` in your **CarouselUsers** component  that grab the Inner Text in `<h6>{user.nome}</h6>` and pass it as props to **SideBarProfile** component .

***like this :***

**CarouselUsers.jsx :**

```
export default function CarouselUsers() {

  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(false)  
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState("")
  const handleClick = (event) => {
      setSelectedUser(event.target.innerText);    
      
  }

  // rest of your code 
  return (
        ......
          {/* GET THE USERNAME */}
            <h6 onClick={handleClick} >{user.nome}</h6>
          {/* GET THE USERNAME */}
          .... rest of your code 
          <SideBarProfile profile={profile} openProfile={openProfile} 
          setSelectedUser = {setSelectedUser} />
        
      )
        
  }
```

**SideBarProfile.jsx :**

```
export default function SideBarProfile({openProfile,profile, setSelectedUser}) {  
  return (
       ......
            <div className="nome text-center">
                      <h5>{setSelectedUser}</h5>
            </div>
        ....
     )
```